# asp.net mvc: Dynamically add child/sub controllers from a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, controller

In asp.net mvc, you can easily call/add a controller from a view, but what is the easiest way to add child/subcontrollers from a controller.  What Im getting at is I want to dynamically build a list of child controllers from within the controller itself, not from the view.

The pattern I have in mind is derived from the old ibuyspy portal/dnn where you come up with a list of pluggable modules that you want to inject into the page. Each module is, itself, a controller, and is ignorant that it is a child request. But, dnn uses the ui/views to inject the modules, as where I want to create a list of modules in the controller, then tell the view to inject them.

Thanks in advance,

Jesse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array of objects in your view model that contains information corresponding to the desired modules, you can inject them into the view using RenderAction like this:

```
<div id="LeftColumn">
    <% foreach (module in Model.Modules) { 
        Html.RenderAction(module.ActionName, module.ControllerName, new {id = module.id}); 
    } %>
</div>
```

RenderAction is a method that calls a method on a controller, and injects the result into the page at the location where RenderAction is called.  It is part of the [ASP.NET MVC Futures assembly.](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2009/04/04/ASPNETMVCPartialViewsHtmlRenderActionASPNETMVCFutures.aspxv)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  I guess it was so simple, I was trying to complicate the issue.  Thanks for setting me right.

Comment: Is there an alternative if we are not using MVC Future Assembly?

Comment: You could try Subcontrollers or RenderPartial.  But RenderAction is going to be included in MVC framework 2.0 anyway.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214052/should-i-use-areas-or-renderaction-in-asp-net-mvc/1214077